# Prime factorization of a factorial

Tags: algorithm, math, primes, factorial, prime-factoring

I need to write a program to input a number and output its factorial's prime factorization  in the form:

```
4!=(2^3)*(3^1)

5!=(2^3)*(3^1)*(5^1)
```

The problem is I still can't figure out how to get that result.

Apparently each first number in brackets is for the ascending prime numbers up until the actual factorial. The second number in brackets is the amount of times the number occurs in the factorial.

What I can't figure out is for example in `5!=(2^3)*(3^1)*(5^1)`, how does 2 only occur 3 times, 3 only 1 time and 5 only one time in 120 (5!=120).

I have now solved this thanks to the helpful people who commented but I'm now having trouble trying to figure out how could I take a number and get the factorial in this format without actually calculating the factorial.

Comment: You're aware that `2*2*2 * 3 * 5` is equal to `120`, right? What confuses you about that?

Comment: I was just confuse where those numbers come from. I have figured it out now.

Comment: Look at my answer towards the bottom. It explains how you can get the prime factorization of the factorial without actually calculating the factorial. Basically, you factor all of the numbers that make up the factorial and add the exponents of like bases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Every number can be represented by a unique (up to re-ordering) multiplication of prime numbers, called the prime factorization of the number, as you are finding the prime factors that can uniquely create that number.

`2^3=8`

`3^1=3`

`5^1=5`

and `8*3*5=120`

But this also means that: `(2^3)*(3^1)*(5^1) = 120`

It's not saying that 2 occurs 3 times as a digit in the number 120, which it obviously does not, but rather to multiply 2 by 2 by 2, for a total of 3 twos. Likewise for the 3 and 5, which occur once in the prime factorization of 120. The expression which you mention is showing you this unique prime factorization of the number 120. This is one way of getting the prime factorization of a number in Python:

```
def pf(number):
    factors=[]
    d=2
    while(number>1):
        while(number%d==0):
            factors.append(d)
            number=number/d
        d+=1
    return factors
```

Running it you get:

```
>>> pf(120)
[2, 2, 2, 3, 5]
```

Which multiplied together give you 120, as explained above. Here's a little diagram to illustrate this more clearly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks the prime factor bit clued me in.

Comment: I understand, although im not familiar with python. My next question is how could I take a number and get the factorial in this format without actually calculating the factorial.

Comment: @Bradg89 you can use the definition of factorial. It is a product of a bunch of factors (components). Each of those factors (components) can be decomposed into prime factors. Therefore the product of factors can be rewritten in terms of the product of the found prime factors of the components -- yielding the answer to your problem without having to compute the factorial at all.

Answer (score 11):

Consider e.g. *`33!`*. It's a product of:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
```

the factors are:

```
2   2   2   2    2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
    2       2          2           2           2           2           2           2
            2                      2                       2                       2
                                   2                                               2
                                                                                   2
  3     3     3        3        3        3        3        3        3        3        3
              3                          3                          3
                                                                    3
      5          5              5              5              5              5
                                                              5
          7                  7                    7                    7
                   11                               11                               11
                         13                                     13
                                     17
                                           19
                                                       23
                                                                         29    31
```

Do you see the pattern?

```
33! = 2^( 33 div 2 + 33 div 4 + 33 div 8 + 33 div 16 + 33 div 32) *
      3^( 33 div 3 + 33 div 9 + 33 div 27) *
      5^( 33 div 5 + 33 div 25) *
      ----
      7^( 33 div 7) * 11^( 33 div 11) * 13^( 33 div 13) *
      ----
      17 * 19 * 23 * 29 * 31
```

Thus, to find prime factorization of *`n!`* without doing any multiplications or factorizations, we just need to have the ordered list of primes not greater than *`n`*, which we process (with a repeated integer division and a possible summation) in three stages - primes that are smaller or equal to the square root of *`n`*; such that are smaller or equal to *`n/2`*; and the rest.

Actually with lazy evaluation it's even simpler than that. Assuming `primes` is already implemented returning a stream of prime numbers in order, in Haskell, factorial factorization is found as

```hs
ff n = [(p, sum . takeWhile (> 0) . tail . iterate (`div` p) $ n) 
         | p <- takeWhile (<= n) primes]

-- Prelude> ff 33
-- [(2,31),(3,15),(5,7),(7,4),(11,3),(13,2),(17,1),(19,1),(23,1),(29,1),(31,1)]
```

because `33 div 4` is `(33 div 2) div 2`, etc..

Answer (score 4):

`2^3` is another way of writing 2<sup><sup>3</sup></sup>, or two to the third power. `(2^3)(3^1)(5^1)` = 2<sup><sup>3</sup></sup> × 3 × 5 = 120.

`(2^3)(3^1)(5^1)` is just the prime factorization of 120 expressed in plain ASCII text rather than with pretty mathematical formatting. Your assignment requires output in this form simply because it's easier for you to output than it would be for you to figure out how to output formatted equations (and probably because it's easier to process for grading).

The conventions used here for expressing equations in plain text are standard enough that you can directly type this text into google.com or wolframalpha.com and it will calculate the result as 120 for you: [(2^3)(3^1)(5^1) on wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%5E3%29%283%5E1%29%285%5E1%29) / [(2^3)(3^1)(5^1) on google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=%282%5E3%29%283%5E1%29%285%5E1%29)

---

WolframAlpha can also compute prime factorizations, which you can use to get test results to compare your program with. For example: [prime factorization of 1000!](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prime+factorization+of+1000%21)

A naïve solution that actually calculates the factorial will only handle numbers up to 12 (if using 32 bit ints). This is because 13! is ~6.2 billion, larger than the largest number that can be represented in a 32 bit int.

However it's possible to handle much larger inputs if you avoid calculating the factorial first. I'm not going to tell you exactly how to do that because either figuring it out is part of your assignment or you can ask your prof/TAs. But below are some hints.

> a<sup>b</sup> × a<sup>c</sup> = a<sup>b+c</sup>

> *equation (a)*      10 = 2<sup>1</sup> × 5<sup>1</sup> 
>   *equation (b)*      15 = 3<sup>1</sup> × 5<sup>1</sup> 
>   10 × 15 = ?      *Answer using the right hand sides of equations (a) and (b), not with the number 150.*

> 10 × 15 = (2<sup>1</sup> × 5<sup>1</sup>) × (3<sup>1</sup> × 5<sup>1</sup>) = 2<sup>1</sup> × 3<sup>1</sup> × (5<sup>1</sup> × 5<sup>1</sup>) = 2<sup>1</sup> × 3<sup>1</sup> × 5<sup>2</sup>
>   
>   As you can see, computing the prime factorization of 10 × 15 can be done without multiplying 10 by 15; You can instead compute the prime factorization of the individual terms and then combine those factorizations.

Comment: Thanks you would be right in assuming that. I will attempt on my own before looking. Can't get a job if I rely on others to do the hard stuff.

Answer (score 3):

If you write out the factorial 5!:

1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5,

you will notice that there is one non-prime number: 4. 4 can be written as 2 * 2 or 2^2, which is where the extra 2s come from.
Add up all of the occurrences (exponential forms are in parentheses; add exponents for like bases):

 2 (2^1) * 3 (3^1) * 4 (2^2) * 5 (5^1), you get the proper answer.

Comment: Readers should note that here "2 (2^1) * 3 (3^1) * 4 (2^2) * 5 (5^1)" doesn't mean "2 × 2¹ × 3 × 3¹ × 4 × 2² × 5 × 5¹", (which evaluates to 120² rather than 120). In this context the parenthesized text simply expands the corresponding term of the factorial rather than acting as terms themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `O(n/2 log log n)` algorithm using only sums (no need precalc primes).

This is a sieve using relation

```
f = a * b  ~>  f^k = a^k * b^k
```

then, we reduce all initial factors `1 * 2 * 3 * ... * n` moving `k` from big numbers to small numbers.

Using Sieve of Atkin the Will Ness algorithm could be better for **very** big `n` if not, I think it could be better

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);
  int *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (n + 1));
  int i, j, d;
  for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    p[i] = 1;
  for(i = n >> 1; i > 1; i--)
    if(p[i]) {
      for(j = i + i, d = 2; j <= n; j += i, d++) {
        if(p[j]) {
          p[i] += p[j];
          p[d] += p[j];
          p[j] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  printf("1");
  for(i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    if(p[i])
      printf(" * %i^%i", i, p[i]);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: sieve of Atkin is reportedly very hard to implement efficiently.

Comment: Good point @WillNess, for that reason I think your aproach is better for very (very) big numbers :) On the other hand, I wonder if Atkin could be used as my sieve to get a better alg. Nice problem!

Comment: I think for very big numbers `N` the output will consist of way too many entries - [about `N / (log N - 1)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function) of them (as many as there are primes below `N`). For 10^9 it's 50,701,542 entries ([actually, 50,847,534](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PrimePi%5B10%5E9%5D)). We won't really need to do *that*, I guess. :) So any normal impl of SoE will do, I think, whether pre-calc'd or as part of the algo. :)

Comment: You've convinced me :) XD XD