# Output powers of prime factors of a factorial

Tags: c++, prime-factoring, exponent

I'm trying to write a code for my class. The program has to let the user input a number and it will output the exponents of each of the prime factors of its factorial. For example, when a user inputs the number 5, the output will be 3 1 1 (2^3, 3^1, 5^1). So far I have the code to get the prime factors of the factorial. But I can't get the exponents.

My code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int number, factor, exp, product, x, factorial=1;

cout <<"PRIME FACTORIALS" <<endl;
cout <<" " <<endl;
cout <<"Welcome! This program allows users to find the prime factors of a number and its exponents or how many times each prime factor is multiplied." <<endl;
cout <<" " <<endl;
cout <<"To begin, please input a positive integer below:" <<endl;
cin >>number;

if ((number<1) || (number>100))
{
    cout <<"You have entered a number that is out of range. Please enter a number from 1-100." <<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    system("cls");
    main();
}

else
{
    for (x=1; x<=number; x++)
    {
        factorial=factorial*x;

        for (factor=2; factor<=factorial; factor++)
        {
            while (factorial%factor==0)
            {
                factorial/=factor;
                cout <<factor <<" ";
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've fixed that. Any idea how I could output the exponents of the prime factors?

Comment: Count how many times the division succeeds for each factor. (Although you're currently trying all possible factors, not just prime factors.)

Comment: cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196814/prime-numbers-and-factorials/21235844#21235844

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you finish computing the factorial before working out its factors? I.e. have a `}` after `factorial = factorial * x;`?