# Prime Factorization in Haskell to return a list of tuples giving the number and the power

Tags: haskell, refactoring, primes, prime-factoring

I have been trying to learn haskell by trying to do some simple problems.

##### The Problem

Currently, I am trying to implement a function `primeFactorization :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]` such that the output is a list of tuples containing the prime factor and the power it is raise to in the number.

##### Example Output

`> primeFactorization 120` 
 
`[(2,3), (3,1), (5,1)]` since 120 = 2^3 * 3^1 * 5^1

##### My (Partial) Solution

```hs
primeFactorization :: Integer -> [Integer]
primeFactorization n = 
    let
        factors :: Integer -> [Integer]
        factors n = [x | x <- [2..n-1], n `mod` x == 0]

        isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
        isPrime n
            | n `elem` [0, 1] = False
            | n == 2 = True
            | n > 2 = null [ x | x <- [2..(ceiling . sqrt . fromIntegral) n], n `mod` x == 0]
            | otherwise = False
    in
        filter isPrime $ (factors n)
```

This is a working implementation to get the prime factors of a number. However as seen it only outputs the prime factors. I am not sure on how to store the number of times in haskell. Also, considering it is un-idiomatic to iterate in haskell I don't know how I would implement the solution. In python, I would do:

```py
def pf(number):
    factors=[]
    d=2
    while(number>1):
        while(number%d==0):
            factors.append(d)
            number=number/d
        d+=1
    return factors
```

So, the question: **How to implement the powers of the prime factors?**

NOTE:

1. I already saw: [Prime factorization of a factorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196814/prime-factorization-of-a-factorial) however that does not answer my question.
2. This is NOT a homework problem, I am learning independently.

Comment: Note that you have known [Haskell expressions for the list of prime numbers](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers). If you don't like the idea of using iteration, you have to formulate the problem in a way that uses recursion. If n is a multiple of prime number p, you have to find a way to combine p with the object (probably of type `[(Integer, Integer)]`) that represents the prime factors of n/p.

Comment: @jpmarinier I understand that I would need to use recursion, but I do not understand how. Also, I am open to using iteration, I just thought it would be un-idiomatic and I want to write idiomatic, readable code. The problem is the only way I know to maintain count is using mutability(`count +=1`), something that I believe is not possible with the built-ins in haskell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always replace imperative-language loops (as long as they don't meddle with any global state) with recursion. That may not be the most elegant approach, but in this case it seems perfectly appropriate to imitate your inner Python loop with a recursive function:

```
dividerPower :: Integer -> Integer -> Int
dividerPower n d
  | n`rem`d == 0  = 1 + dividerPower (n`quot`d) d
  | otherwise     = 0
```

(This counts “backwards” compared to the Python loop. You could also make it tail-recursive with a helper function and count forwards over an accumulator variable, but that's more awkward and I don't think there's a memory/performance benefit that would justify it in this case.)

You can either use that together with your Haskell code (for each of the factors you've already found, check how often it occurs), or extend it so the whole thing works like the Python solution (which is actually a lot more efficient, because it avoids for every number checking whether it's prime). For that you just need to give back the final `n` in the result. Let's use a `where` block for handling the pattern matching, and also make the `rem` and:

```
dividePower :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Int)
dividePower n d
  | r == 0     = (nfin, p'+1)
  | otherwise  = (n, 0)
 where (n', r) = n `quotRem` d
       (nfin, p') = dividePower n' d
```

Then the equivalent to your Python code is

```
pf :: Integer -> Integer -> [(Integer, Int)]
pf = go 2
 where go d n
         | n>1        = (d, p) : go (d+1) n'
         | otherwise  = []
        where (n', p) = dividePower n d
```

This actually gives you, like in Python, the list including also non-dividers (with power 0). To avoid that, change the list-building to

```
         | n>1        = (if p>0 then ((d,p):) else id) $ go (d+1) n'
```

Comment: Hey @leftaroundabout, thanks for the answer! However, I don't understand the function `dividePower`. The condition `r==0` returns an `Int`, not a tuple as it should be. Could you please clarify that>

Comment: @NaitikMundra mistake there, corrected now.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was just wondering about the complexity of this function. Given that lazy evaluation and recursion are being used quite a lot here, I cannot figure it out. My best (guess) is O(n)

Comment: Pretty sure it's not O(n). At any rate `pf` should perform the same as your Python version.